# Assert exception with parameters using Junit

Tags: java, exception, junit, expected-exception

How can I check that an Exception with specific parameters is thrown, using ExpectedException. Suppose I have AcmeException which returns different error messages based on the parameters: AcmeException(One) returns One while AcmeException(One,two,three) returns Three. I am not interested in their return messages while testing but rather the exact exception with it's parameter list.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
@Test
@Verifies(value= "should fail with AcmeException", method = "acmeMethod(String, String, String)")
public void acmeMethod_shouldFailWithAcmeException()
        throws Exception {
    //TODO auto-generated
    //Set some global paramater

    //Here only the generic exception type is checked
    exception.expect(AcmeException.class);
    exception.expectMessage("Some Message returned by AcmeException");
    new acmeMethod_shouldFailWithAcmeException();
```

Exception (ShortPasswordException):

```
/**
* Password exception when the length is less than the minimum allowed.
* <p>

* @since 1.5
*/
public class ShortPasswordException extends PasswordException {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 31620091002L;

public ShortPasswordException() {
    super("error.password.length");
}

public ShortPasswordException(String message) {
    super(message);
   }
 }
```

The above exception is called here:

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(lengthGp) && password.length() < minLength) {

        if ("true".equals(caseGp) && "true".equals(digitGp) && "true".equals(nonDigitGp)) {
            throw new ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length.case_digit_nondigit", lengthGp));
        } else if ("true".equals(digitGp) && "true".equals(nonDigitGp)) {
            throw new ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length.digit_nondigit", lengthGp));
        } else if ("true".equals(caseGp) && "true".equals(nonDigitGp)) {
            throw new ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length.case_nondigit", lengthGp));
        } else if ("true".equals(caseGp) && "true".equals(digitGp)) {
            throw new ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length.case_digit_nondigit", lengthGp));
        } else if ("true".equals(nonDigitGp)) {
            throw new ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length.nondigit", lengthGp));
        } else if ("true".equals(digitGp)) {
            throw new ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length.digit", lengthGp));
        } else if ("true".equals(caseGp)) {
            throw new ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length.case", lengthGp));
        } else {
            throw new ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length", lengthGp));
        }
    }
```

Now while testing I would like to know when

```
ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length.case_digit_nondigit", lengthGp));
```

Or

```
ShortPasswordException(getMessage("error.password.length.case_digit_nondigit", lengthGp))
```

Is thrown after having changed the values of the global properties.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The last instruction posted doesn't even compile: it has a redundant parenthesis, and tries to call the method as if it was a constructor. Have you read http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html? Because it explains everything, with examples.

Comment: @JBNizet It's just sample code to explain the problem. In simple terms I have two versions of AcmeException, different by their parameters. RIght now testing only considers the exception without their parameters, I would like to have it check the exception plus the arguments list.

Comment: Parameters are passed when constructing the exception. Once JUnit has the exception, what should it check? Its message? Something returned by a getter on the exception? Show the code of the exception. Show the code throwing the exception. Explain with a concrete example what you want to check.

Comment: @JBNizet Updated. Does it make sense now?

Comment: exception.getMessage() will return the message passed in the constructor of the exception. So, if the value returned by `getMessage("error.password.length.case_digit_nondigit", lengthGp)` is "Hello world", you can check that the exception message is indeed "Hello World", using `exception.expectMessage("Hello world")`.

Comment: @JBNizet That is correct what I aimed to achieve was decouple tests from the text messages (which could be changed) and let them depend only on the global properties keys passed as arguments to the exception.

Comment: Then use `exception.expectMessage(getMessage("error.password.length.case_digit_nondigit", lengthGp))`